# Why is my y axis between 0 and 1 on my ggplot barplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

When I am plotting this ggplot in r, my y axis is labeled between 0 and 1. I don't understand where this comes from, as my values are not only comprised between 0 and 1? I would like my y axis to represent the values of my data frame.

Here is a sample of my data:

```
mydata<-data.frame(
  value=runif(6,0,100),
  type=rep(c("a","b"),6),
  animal=c("h","h","c","c","c","h"),
  eval=c(1,2,1,2,1,1), 
  frame2=letters[1:6])

ggplot(mydata,aes(x = frame2, y = value, fill=type)) + 
  theme_classic()+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('#bcbbb8','#FFFFFF','#ffce0c'))+
  geom_bar(position = "fill",stat = "identity")+
  facet_grid(animal ~ eval)

head(mydata)

      value type animal eval frame2
1 76.190681    a      h    1      a
2 82.086541    b      h    2      b
3 14.002725    a      c    1      c
4 67.064677    b      c    2      d
5  3.035823    a      c    1      e
6 55.560134    b      h    1      f
```

[image]

Comment: I think you need to have the `aes` inside the `geom_bar` and remove the `position = "fill"`

Comment: @akrun great, removing `position="fill"` was enough.

Comment: Thanks, I posted my solution as answer

Comment: Check that this generates the intended result. It looks from the chart as though some groups are summed to give values > 100.

Comment: It also resolved another issue I had with `theme(panel.spacing = unit(1, "lines"))` having no effect on the figure.

Comment: @neilfws thanks, this is because of the way I generated the sample of the data but I don't have this issue in the real data set where each combination of factors is unique. I will edit my question to make it more general (not just 0 to 100).

Comment: @Nakx  In your data, there are 2 values for each combination of 'frame2', 'animal', 'eval'.  So it is taking the `sum` by default.  you can change it using `stat_summary`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this by removing the `position = "fill`

```
ggplot(mydata,aes(x = frame2, y = value, fill=type)) + 
   theme_classic()+
   geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
   facet_grid(animal ~ eval)
```

NOTE: Using the default colors instead of the custom ones where one of them is 'white'.

-output

[image]